# Webview not appearing in Expo Web

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-webview

Working fine in expo mobile app, but same code doesn't show anything when opening Expo App on Web browser by running command `expo start --web`

Here is the sample code

```
    <WebView 
     originWhitelist={['*']} 
     source={{ uri: 'https://sofit.ltd' }}
     style={{marginBottom:100, height:"100%", width:"100%" }}
    />
```

Answer (score 5):

Did you try in web only? 
try this snack:
https://snack.expo.io/@djalik/webview-demo

Comment: Mentioned code is working fine in mobile but causing issue on web ,
And I have tried {{ flex:1 }} too, but no luck.

Comment: You are using in web not in device

Comment: Yes, I am using expo web to run my app in browser.

Comment: i updated the answer, you have to use iframe, look at snack in answer

Comment: Okay so you are saying that I have to use iframe to display view in web?

Comment: Thanks it worked, but now I have added the actual website which I want to display, but returns error in log.
"Multiple 'X-Frame-Options' headers with conflicting values ('SAMEORIGIN, DENY') encountered when loading "

Comment: If you have access to server side of the site you can make something  like this: Response.Headers.Remove("X-Frame-Options");

Comment: Or run chrome in dev with insecure mode

Comment: 1: We have no access to server, 
2: If we run chrome in dev with insecure mode, then it won't work in production.

Comment: I answered your main question: in web no webview html tag, you can use only  iframe for site page browsing.

Answer (score 0):

For me the answer was to wrap it with a View:

```
<View style={styles.container}>
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
      <View style={styles.webviewContainer}>
        <WebView
            originWhitelist={['*']}
            source={{ uri: currentURI }}
            ref={webViewRef}
            style={styles.webview}
          />
      </View>
</View>

// Styles
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    marginTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  webview: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  webviewContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    alignSelf: 'stretch',
  },
});
```